# SQL request on an Excel read-only file doesn't use up-to-date file version

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I'm using ADODB (in Excel) to do a SQL request on two Excel files: file A (.xlsb) and file B (.xlsm). This request is executed from file B. The code starts and execute the first request on file A pretty easily! However, when it comes to execute the request on file B (i.e. on itself), if this file is in read-only, then, the request returns 0x80040E07 (-2147219793), Data type mismatch in criteria expression error.  However, if File B is opened with read-write permission, the request goes through easily. How can the fact that a file is read-only throw a Data mismatch error?

So, here is my minimal working exemple. First, in the References of my project, I added Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library.

Here are the connection strings:

File A:

```
DBconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & sourcefile & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;Empty Text Mode=EmptyAsNull"";"
```

File B:

```
SourceFile_Self = ThisWorkbook.FullName
Connect_Self = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & SourceFile_Self & ";" & _
               "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;Empty Text Mode=EmptyAsNull"";"
```

The opening of both connections are working fine, that's when I try to get the request to execute on the file B that I get into errors:

File A:

```
Dim objconnection as ADODB.Connection
Set objconnection = new ADODB.Connection
objconnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objconnection.Open (DBconnect)


Dim objRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset

szSQL = "SELECT [Equivalent bore diameter] " & _
        "FROM " & SourceSheet & _
        " WHERE [Shaft dia] = " & MotorShaftDia & ";"

Set objRecordset = objconnection.Execute(szSQL)
```

File B:

```
Set objselfConnection = New ADODB.Connection
objselfConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objselfConnection.Open (Connect_Self)


Dim objRecordSetSheetMetal As ADODB.Recordset
Set objRecordSetSheetMetal = New ADODB.Recordset

SQLQuery = "SELECT [" & SeekedColumnTitle & "] as PartNumber, SUM([Total net area (SQ FT)]) as TotalQTY, [Standard Material Description], [OPER], [Sundries], [Unit], [To be ordered (if selected)] as OrderedBOM " & _
            "FROM [" & CabinetWorksheetName & "$] " & _
            "WHERE [Selected] ='X' " & _
            "GROUP BY [" & SeekedColumnTitle & "], [Standard Material Description], [OPER],[Sundries], [Unit], [To be ordered (if selected)];"


Set objRecordSetSheetMetal = objselfConnection.Execute(SQLQuery) '<--- That's where my problem is happening
```

I did not try to convert my code to the Recordset.Open syntax to see if my problem is still present, because I suspect this is more related to how ADOBD is doing a request on the file, than to some arithmetic error.

I know a lot of thing are wrong in this exemple, but, please remember the main topic here...

EDIT: 
Anyhow, I've tried to focus on troubleshooting best practices! I tried removing parts until it worked, then adding back parts until it didn't. Finally, I found the problem seems to be here :

```
SUM([Total net area (SQ FT)]) as TotalQTY
```

This field is calculated in my file (its a formula that gives its value). The value of this field is "#N/A" [adVarWChar type] in the read-only file, while it is 28.866 [adDouble type] in the read-write file. You cannot do a sum of characters strings! The field is a formula that takes 2 values (height and width) and multiply them. It seems that those two parameters, coming from another page, are not updated, leading to the "#N/A" error.

It's really like if the table queried by ADODB isn't the most recent one [it seems like it is referring to the dataset as it was, before the opening of the file]. I've tried to save the file (using Save As), then opening again this file as read-only and the request pass through (because the fields are now evaluated as double). But, if I modify one of the value, this updated value isn't shown in the results, comforting my hypothesis that ADODB is doing the request on the last saved version of the file (not the current/displayed one).

Comment: I think that you have to add reference for "Microsoft Activex Data Objects Library" to your VBA Project. You can take a look at this blog : https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/ado-sql-macros-connecting-database/

Comment: @Mohamad, Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library is already added to my Project.